# Double Quotes in Bash's variable substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting, variable-substitution

I am trying to configure some software packages with a script thereby I got the following problem. Assume that the environment variable `PREFIX` is set to the location where I plan to install the software. Inside my script I have

```
CONFOPTS="--enable-shared --with-blas=\"-L${PREFIX}/lib/ -lblas\" --with-lapack=\"-L${PREFIX}/lib -llapack\""
echo CONFOPTS=$CONFOPTS
```

which prints

```
CONFOPTS=--enable-shared --with-blas="-L/scratch/test/lib/ -lblas" --with-lapack="-L/scratch/test/lib -llapack"
```

If a want to run configure afterwards in the script

```
set -x
./configure --prefix=${PREFIX} ${CONFOPTS}
set +x
```

it gets expanded to

```
 ./configure --prefix=/scratch/test --enable-shared '--with-blas="-L/scratch/test/lib/' '-lblas"' '--with-lapack="-L/scratch/test/lib' '-llapack"'
```

which is rubbish and misinterpreted by the configure script and the shell. The correct one would be

```
./configure --prefix=/scratch/test --enable-shared --with-blas="-L/scratch/test/lib/ -lblas" --with-lapack="-L/scratch/test/lib -llapack"
```

How can I change the behavior such that I obtain a proper command line in the configure call?

Answer (score 1):

Put your options into an array instead, then you can quote it:

```
declare -a CONFOPTS
CONFOPTS=(
    '--enable-shared'
    "--with-blas=-L${PREFIX}/lib/ -lblas"
    "--with-lapack=-L${PREFIX}/lib -llapack"
)


./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" "${CONFOPTS[@]}"
```

---

*I'm not sure if I have separated your options correctly, please let me know if you need help making adjustments.*

---

If you really need to maintain those double quotes and pass them to `configure`, try this:

```
declare -a CONFOPTS
CONFOPTS=(
    '--enable-shared'
    '--with-blas="-L${PREFIX}/lib/ -lblas"'
    '--with-lapack="-L${PREFIX}/lib -llapack"'
)


./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" "${CONFOPTS[@]}"
```

---

Or even this?:

```
declare -a CONFOPTS
CONFOPTS=(
    '--enable-shared'
    "--with-blas=\"-L${PREFIX}/lib/ -lblas\""
    "--with-lapack=\"-L${PREFIX}/lib -llapack\""
)


./configure --prefix="${PREFIX}" "${CONFOPTS[@]}"
```

Comment: In general this would work but many parts of the code require CONFOPTS to be a string rather than being an array. So this solution will not work easily for my purpose.

Comment: The configure script is a GNU autotools like one, for example from GNU Octave, where I first recognized this problem.

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu, Can you try the last example in my answer?  I think this is what you need.

Comment: The last 2 solutions (putting double quotes inside the arg) wont work properly as the shell is just going to pass literal quotes to `./configure`. The first option is the right way.

Comment: @Patrick, I think he needs to prevent word splitting on those arguments (`--with-lapack=-L${PREFIX}/lib -llapack`) so that whole line is passed as a single argument.

Comment: I tried the second and the third one and none of them gives the correct result. There are stil the single quotes around the whole `--with-...` construction: `./configure --prefix=/scratch/test/ --enable-shared '--with-blas="-L/scratch/test/lib/ -lblas"' '--with-lapack="-L/scratch/test/lib -llapack"'`. If the single quotes are remove everything works fine.

Comment: I found a dirty workaround which does the right thing without using arrays and similar stuff. I replaced the call to configure by: `eval $(printf "./configure --prefix=%s %s" "${PREFIX}" "${CONFOPTS}")`

Comment: @M.K.akaGrisu, note that the single quotes around the arguments in the output of `set -x` are there just to make the output unambiguous. They also make the output usable as input to the shell, so you need to use the shell's quoting rules to interpret them.